# How to send Ctrl+Alt+End to Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have an application where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> is mapped to a command, but when using the machine via Remote Desktop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> is used by the system as an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Is there any way to change that setting for the Remote Desktop session so I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> in my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the option of running [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) on the remote PC?  You could run a script there which would trap an alternate hotkey of your choosing, and render it (there) as Ctrl+Alt+End.

Answer (score 14):

Alternate method which opens the '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>' overlay manually:

```
Run > shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

or

```
cmd > explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Comment: Related (possible explanation?): https://serverfault.com/questions/546644/how-do-i-change-active-directory-password-in-windows-2012-terminal-server-withou

Comment: Thank you, this is extra-handy for use in a remote inside another remote (where the ctrl+alt+end is caught by the first layer)

Answer (score 2):

Use **On-Screen Keyboard**.

1. Click Windows button -> Run
2. Open `osk` and click related key.

Comment: If it does not work, try pressing Ctrl, and Alt on physical keyboard, hold and then click "End" on On-Screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to install on the remote machine, you could use a scripting engine like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) to make a small script to catch whatever shortcut you would like and virtually "press" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on the remote machine for you.

Comment: No need for install permissions; AHK works as a user-mode executable, so as long as application execution isn't restricted it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you're connecting, on the Local Resources tab of your Remote Desktop Client choose **"On the Local Computer"** in the drop-down menu of the Keyboard frame.  This will send those keyboard signals directly to the remote machine instead of via the client.

Comment: disabling the Windows key combinations actually didn't seem to apply to Ctrl+Alt+End.  Good suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using Powershell. This worked for me in a slightly different and more complicated setup (connecting from a Mac laptop (no "end" key on keyboard) to a Linux server through SSH and then from the Linux server to a Windows Server 2016 server through Remote desktop protocol using the `rdesktop` Linux RDP command line client).

In Windows:

1. Click Start menu
2. Click in the search bar
3. Type "powershell"
4. In the search results, click "powershell.exe"
5. In the PowerShell shell that opens, type the following:

   ```
   Powershell -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -command "(new-object -ComObject 
   shell.application).WindowsSecurity()"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Also from PowerShell (if any other combinations doesn't work)

```
(New-Object -COM Shell.Application).WindowsSecurity()
```

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes it does. Just because an answer is short doesn't mean it's not an answer. See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627)

Comment: Its not the length of the command, but the fact that it has not been explained.

Comment: @RohitGupta Still, that's not a reason to delete it. See [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260411/4284627). Deletion is only for things that don't answer the question at all, like "Could you clarify?" or "I'm having this problem too". If it's an answer but you don't think it's a *good* answer, you can downvote it and leave a comment explaining why you don't think it's a good answer.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, point taken.  I normally suggest that they add an explanation or citation.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to send keys is to use a client like "Remote Desk Connection Manager" or others to connect to your nested server. Now on the server list, you may right click to send combined keys like Ctrl+Alt+Delete to bring up the  security menu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).