# Remote Desktop: Sending Ctrl-Alt-Left Arrow/Ctrl-Alt-Right Arrow to the remote PC

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I need use the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> in an application on my computer. When I use Remote Desktop to connect to that computer, either the Remote Desktop Client (mstsc.exe) or the RDP server implementation swallow these key combinations. The combos appear to be reserved to the Remote Desktop, although they don't seem to be doing anything.

Is there a way (supported or not) to disable this behavior so that the key combinations are sent to my application?

**Update 2022-12-01:** As noted by [Bragolgirith](https://superuser.com/questions/327866/remote-desktop-sending-ctrl-alt-left-arrow-ctrl-alt-right-arrow-to-the-remote-p?noredirect=1#comment2726325_327866), this was fixed in version [1.2.2924](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/whats-new-client-windows#updates-for-version-122924) of the Remote Desktop client for Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send Ctrl+Alt+End to Remote Desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/92801/how-to-send-ctrlaltend-to-remote-desktop)

Comment: This combinations are Remote Desktop's hotkeys (https://serverfault.com/a/73568/238181)

Comment: Update: this was fixed in RD on 2022-02-23: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/whats-new-client-windows#updates-for-version-122924

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The hotkeys
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
are eaten up by the Remote Desktop Client.
Their only effect is to switch you to back to the host computer.

It looks like this was some intended feature that was never fully programmed
and completed, but there is no way to turn it off.
These hotkeys are not even listed by Microsoft in its official documentation at
[Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-shortcut-keys?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

**Solution 1 : Use the Microsoft Store version**

Another version of RDP can be found in the Microsoft Store at
[Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#).

This version does not have this semi-implemented feature, so it lets through
these hotkeys without a problem.
This was verified on Windows 10 version 1903.

**Solution 2 : Translate the hotkeys on both client and server**

This solution will use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
installed on both client and server, to:

- On the client, translate the above hotkeys to others that are not intercepted
  by RDP
- On the server, translate these keys back to the above hotkeys.

You may for example use on the client the following AutoHotkey script "rdp hotkeys_slave.ahk" to convert
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
;Send Alt+Win+Left when user types Ctrl+Alt+Left
^!Left::
send !#{Left}
return

;Send Alt+Win+Right when user types Ctrl+Alt+Right
^!Right::
send !#{Right}
return
```

The script is restricted to the mstsc.exe process using
[#IfWin[Not]Active / #IfWin[Not]Exist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Unfortunately Autohotkey scripts only work in full screen RDP once they are restarted *after activating the fullscreen* (See here: [How to fix AHK to send keys to RDP fullscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/397257/how-to-fix-ahk-to-send-keys-to-rdp-fullscreen)) So we need a second script "rdp hotkeys_master.ahk" to achieve this:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, ReloadOnRDPMaximized, 500
return

ReloadOnRDPMaximized:
If WinActive("ahk_class TscShellContainerClass")
{
    WinGet, maxOrMin, MinMax, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass

    if (maxOrMin = 0) {
        WinGetPos, PosX, PosY, WinWidth, WinHeight, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass

        if (PosY = 0) {
            ; it is fully maximized therefore reload "script.ahk"
            Run "autohotkey" "rdp hotkeys_slave.ahk"

            ; wait until window gets deactivated so you don't reload it again.
            WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass

        }
    }
}
```

You may use on the server the following AutoHotkey script to convert
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>:

```
;Send Ctrl+Alt+Left when user types Ctrl+Win+Left
!#Left::
send !^{Left}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Right when user types Ctrl+Win+Right
!#Right::
send !^{Right}
return
```

To make the scripts run on startup put all of them in the autostart folder on the respective devices (type Win+R and shell:startup)

Comment: Yes, just awarded you the bounty. This didn't lead me to a solution I wanted to but it answered the question so that I believe it will stop people from riposting the same question elsewhere. Great job!

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but the problem is that the ctrl-alt-keys are now not usable on the local system because they are translated. Is it possible to only do the translation when the focus is in the RDP app?

Comment: I know this is old, but yes, start the ahk script with this line:

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe mstsc.exe

Comment: Microsoft Store's Remote Desktop doesn't support multi monitor setups (

Comment: The same issue arises for vmware workstation. Take a look at`Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Hot Keys`

Comment: Is there any equivalent solution to the Microsoft Store version for a Mac client?

Comment: @andresp: I don't know of one, but I'm not on the Mac.

Comment: I wasted hours trying to get this auto hotkey script to work consistently and eventually gave up. This is a nightmare..

Comment: @JasonGallavin: My answer was modified by another user, so I can take no responsibility. My apologies.

Comment: @harrymc you're good. I was just frustrated that it's this hard to use standard hot keys. It works sort of. The issue is sometimes the windows key gets through and triggers Microsoft office to open. Idk if there is a way to modify autohotkey to be more consistent or if it's just an issue with autohotkey not always catching.

Comment: @JasonGallavin: In my experience AHK is very reliable. It's perhaps a racing condition between it and the RDP software, where AHK is mostly but not always the winner.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the poster and the answers so far; these helped me solve my similar issue:  I have keyboard shortcuts on my desktop PC's text editor that use <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+...</kbd>, and I wanted to be able to use them when accessing the machine remotely.

With this AHK script, I type <kbd>Win</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and I'm able to accomplish the commented commands below.  Now regardless of which PC I use to access the remote desktop PC (i.e., when home or traveling), I can use my shortcuts (and Win is pretty near Alt).  Here's my AHK script:

```
;Send Ctrl+Alt+Left keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Left
^#Left::
send !^{Left}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Right keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Right
^#Right::
send !^{Right}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Up keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Up
^#Up::
send !^{Up}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Down keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Down
^#Down::
send !^{Down}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Shift+Left
^#+Left::
send !^+{Left}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Right keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Shift+Right
^#+Right::
send !^+{Right}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Shift+Up
^#+Up::
send !^+{Up}
return

;Send Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Down keys when user types Ctrl+Win+Shift+Down
^#+Down::
send !^+{Down}
return
```

Note, I use "Apply windows key combinations...On the remote computer" in Remote Desktop Connection, so I run this script *on the remote computer*.

While there are probably more efficient AHK ways to do this, the above works for me. Hope this helps someone else, too.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to share a shorter `Autohotkey` script that will fix **all** `Alt` combinations intercepted by RDP.

The script does not remap a common combination which depends on the `#` key, thus results in almost zero conflicts as combinations with the `AppsKey` are very rare.

**Client**

```
*^LAlt::^AppsKey
return
```

**Server**

```
*^AppsKey::^LAlt
return
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution and worked for me.

Comment: how to modify this script to use only with mstsc ?

Answer (score 2):

For using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> in Far Manager I used the following AutoHotKey script:

```
!^Right::
send ^+{F9}
return

!^Left::
send ^+{F8}
return
```

… where under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F9</kbd> I have Far macros which do the same as when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

This workaround only works if in Properties, the connection option *Keyboard* is set to "On this computer".

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because I ended up doing something similar: I, too, have an AutoHotKey script on my host computer that captures and translates the key combo to a different one; then I have a second AutoHotKey script on the remote computer that translates it back to the original key combo.

Comment: But, this option force the remote user to change the shortcut used remotely, right?

Comment: There's another answer now that shows how to use AutoHotKey to translate the key sequence to something other on the client, then translate it back on the server: https://superuser.com/a/1514904/79488. I'm marking that one as the accepted answer now because it's more complete and contains more details.

Still, kudos for the idea of using AutoHotKey!

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, if you need Ctrl + Alt + Up to work in VSCode a less painful way is just to remap it to say Ctrl + Alt + Num8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Keyboard settings set to something appropriate for how you use RDP. Have a look in the options for your RDP connection, on the Local Resources Tab.

If you always have the connection full screen then set it to "Only when using the full screen" but if you don't use RDP in full screen then set it to "On the remote computer."

[image: RDP Key Combo]

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I always have the connection full screen, and the "Local Resources/Keyboard" settings are set to "Only when using the full screen". This means I can use Alt-Tab and the like, but I still canot use Ctrl-Alt-Left Arrow or Ctrl-Alt-Right Arrow.

Comment: I find that Ctrl-Alt-Up and Ctrl-Atl-Down do work; but Ctrl-Alt-Left and Ctrl-Alt-Right no longer do.  Although they all used to work until recently.

Comment: I find this really annoying, mstsc.exe doesn't seem to matter what I try Ctrl-Alt-Left and Ctrl-Alt-Right doesn't work. The other Remote Desktop app (maybe only available in Windows 10) does pass on those keystrokes but it has other limitations such as no dual monitor support and seems to disconnect a bunch for me.

Comment: Sadly the settings only apply for "WIN key" or "ALT+TAB" as documented here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files

Answer (score 0):

Not so much as a solution, so much as a workaround. I removed the bookmark shortcuts and replaced them with the Navigation shortcuts. This will give up Bookmark shortcuts 9 and 10.

In IntelliJ in the Remote Desktop:
Help -> Find Action..
Type "Back" in the input field and it should bring up the Navigation Back including displaying the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Left.
Press "Alt+Enter"
Press "Ctrl+9" and click Ok.

Repeat process for Forward.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution:
you can add new keyboard short cut.

File->setting-> Keymap->nevigation-> Back-> Add Keyboard Shortcut

[image: Screenshot of menu selection in Settings]