# Can an RDP client prevent “Windows 10 Keylogger” from accessing what is typed on client computer during a session to a remote computer?

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop, privacy, keylogger

The “improve inking and typing” setting in Windows 10 allows Microsoft to send themselves processed samples of what is typed on a machine (not sure if it is processed to remove details as it’s typed such as in RAM somehow or at Microsoft after they received it).

Is this still applicable through an RDP session? Meaning, can windows diagnostics (Microsoft) grab what is typed on the keyboard of the client computer that is sent to the remote computer during an RDP session if the setting is turned on on the client computer, but turned off on the remote computer?

I was thinking maybe RDP diverts the keystrokes to the drivers of the remote computer, bypassing the client computer hopefully keeping it from accessing what is typed into the remote computer for obvious security purposes.

Thank you!

Comment: I would think so, but it would be impossible to test

Comment: "I was thinking maybe RDP diverts the keystrokes to the drivers of the remote computer" - This does happen but "improved inking and typing" also is running locally on the remote computer.  You can just disable it.

Comment: @Ramhound Unless the “improve inking and typing” was already disabled on the remote computer, right? Then it wouldn’t matter if it was enabled or not on the client computer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about RDP, the local computer has first handling
of any input, deciding what to pass over to RDP and what to handle
locally. Some key-presses are not passed on to the RDP session,
or passed differently.

This means that the local computer's "improve inking and typing"
setting is relevant, but perhaps also that of the remote computer.

Most organizations disable the "improve inking and typing" setting on
all their computers, for these obvious security concerns.

As proof of my claims about the working of RDP, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1514904/8672) of mine
that worked for many users. This answer is based on the local computer
having first hand-on for any typed text.

Comment: So does this mean that there is a chance, depending on how everything is set up, that ‘improve inking and typing’ on a BYOD computer may not grab what is typed into the remote computer via RDP or clients//web clients?

Comment: I don't think there's such a chance - it's the local hardware/driver/software that does the input, only passing on to RDP what it doesn't handle locally. It basically handles everything locally first, remote later.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).