# How can I send a Ctrl+Alt+Delete through Remote Desktop in Windows 8?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8, ctrl-alt-delete

I need to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> to a remote machine through Remote Desktop. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> is being intercepted by Windows 8, regardless of whether the remote desktop has focus or is in full screen. I'm remoting in to a Windows XP machine, and I've tried launching Remote Desktop through both the desktop and the Modern UI. How can I send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>?

I'd rather not install anything on the machine.

Comment: Is this through mstsc? or through the new Mondern-UI app?

Comment: The special thing about Ctl-Alt-Del is that it's intercepted by the BIOS (hardware) at the local machine. So you can't actually send that. You would have to use some other key combination and send some kind of "reset" command to the remote machine.

Comment: @JaredTritsch They seem to spawn the same thing.

Comment: @Keith This was possible in Windows 7.

Comment: What is the end goal that you need to achieve by sending CTRL+ALT+DEL ?

Comment: @frozenkoi My end goal was to log in to the Administrator account on XP. I've worked around it since.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send Ctrl+Alt+End to Remote Desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/92801/how-to-send-ctrlaltend-to-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 503, accepted):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> instead.

Comment: Good idea and very handy! However in this particular instance I need a real Ctrl+Alt+Delete. This might end up being all I get though.

Comment: I was under the impression that the result would be a "real Ctrl+Alt+Delete". What's missing?

Comment: @WilliamJackson This pulls up task manager.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 on my Macbook Unibody Late 2008 and I was unable to do Ctrl+Alt+End using my keyboard (even pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fn+Left). To workaround this, I attached a proper Pc keyboard and Ctrl+Alt+End worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it works for mstsc'ing to Windows machine. But it doesn't work for me: I want to send it to remote linux.

Comment: What if you RDP into machine 1, and then use machine 1's RDP to remote desktop into machine 2.  How do you ctrl+alt+del machine 2?

Comment: @edymtt Just saw this comment... It's Fn+Right for the End button

Comment: @user785179 on the first RDP session bring up the on screen keyboard applet, and click on the second (inner) RDP session, then click back to the keyboard and press CTRL ALT END with your mouse, which should send CTRL ALT END to the second RDP session. Convoluted, but just got me out of a jam

Comment: On a Win 8 client running vanilla mstsc rdp'ing into a Win2003 server Ctrl-alt-end within the mstsc window does exactly what Ctrl-alt-del would do on the Win2003 server itself... Solved?

Comment: This only works if the local machine is using mstsc, Running FreeRDP needs other solutions, the Sticky key one was an acceptable workaround for me.

Answer (score 74):

If you're using an **RDP within another RDP**, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> may not work as expected -- it sometimes could bring up the Task Manager / Change Password screen for the outer RDP.

Instead, **to bring up the Task Manager / Change Password screen for the inner RDP :**

1. Bring up the on-screen keyboard (Start > Run, type `osk.exe`)
2. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> on the top-level machine and
   click <kbd>Del</kbd> on the OSK.

This should work for any number of nested RDPs.

Comment: This will only work if you are actually able to run a program. In emergency situations when there's no Desktop and no Menu Button, the mentioned Keystroke seems to be the only option.

Comment: Found this useful for a password reset, using Xfreerdp to connect to Windows.

Comment: lifesaver if you need "remote desktop" inside "remote desktop"

Comment: This worked for me using xfreerdp through pcoip, thanks!

Comment: This just pops up a a cryptic notification saying `"To use the commands available when you press Ctrl+Alt+Del, click your user tile and choose an option"`

Answer (score 50):

On a Mac, running OSX, try <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

This works with [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417) client for OSX.

Comment: From there, the 'Restart' option is available under the Power menu in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 19):

Scenario: Your PC (node_1) and Remote PC (node_2).

Open the onscreen keyboard `Start -> All Programs -> Accesories -> Ease of Access -> On-Screen Keyboard` on node_2.

When you want to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> in node_1 and click <kbd>del</kbd> in node_2. (Worked for me in node_1=XP and node_2=Win7)

Answer (score 18):

**STICKY KEYS IS THE ANSWER**

There is another way which will work regardless of OS and as many nested RDC sessions as you can wrap your head round.
With the focus in the inner most RDC session, quickly press the shift key 5 times. This will bring up the Sticky Keys window, and one window for each level of nesting.
When prompted to turn on sticky keys, click Yes/Ok for your most nested session, and No/Cancel for the outer sessions.
Now with the focus still on the inner most nested session, press ctrl (then let go), press alt (then let go), press delete.

Tadah!

To turn off sticky keys, with the focus on the nested session, press shift 6 times and click No/Cancel.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I disagree. I don't have win7 to test the solution, but if it works as advertised, it does exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: Worked for me inside an RDP session within a VMware VM. Thank you!

Comment: This works. Seems so damn clunky but, it is Windows. The nested RDP sessions are a pain. You'd think they could make an alternative.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me for a RDP inside a VMWare Horizon session inside a RDP (don’t ask why)

Comment: OMG, this finally worked, unlike all the rest on this page. You saved my life, thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

It is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> for people using Citrix.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't a very quick or graceful solution, but if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> doesn't work for what you need, you can open the on-screen keyboard in the remote desktop, and click the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> keys with the mouse.

Comment: doesn't work with Windows-8 (I'm not talking about RDC). On your Windows 8 system, hitting Ctrl + Alt + Del on would thrown a message asking you to use your mouse and click on the user tile:)

Comment: @GrahamWager actually suggested this in chat. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish Does [Anup's workaround work on Win8?](http://superuser.com/a/826064/114388).

Comment: This works for Windows Core! It brings up a DOS shell with a menu of items.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try installing [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) on the server, and create a key binding that works to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> without Windows 8 intercepting it. A [mini-tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) is available as well

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't work.

Comment: The OP specifically specified 'no additional software'.

Comment: @cybermonkey not specifically, he requested it. Still doable

Answer (score 4):

Hope it will help for Windows 8 too.

**Problem**

Unable to use Ctrl+Alt+Del feature on remote desktop running Vista OS/ Windows 7/ Windows 2008.

**Cause**

Problems to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> feature on remote desktops running Vista OS/ Windows 7/ Windows-2008 may occur due to one or more of the following reasons:

> 1. User Access Control(UAC) is disabled in the remote machine running
>      Vista OS/ Windows 7/ Windows 2008.
> 2. Secure Attention Sequence(SAS) is disabled in the remote machine
>      running Vista OS/ Windows 7/ Windows 2008.

**Resolution**

Enable UAC in the Remote Desktop running Vista OS/ Windows 7/ Windows 2008

> Goto Start → Run → type msconfig. This opens the System
>   Configuration Window.
>
> Click on Tools tab.
>
> Locate and Click
>
> on "Enable UAP" or "Enable UAC" option item. This opens a Command
>   Prompt   window that automatically executes and runs certain process
>   to Enable UAC.
>
> Close the cmd window when done. Also close
>   msconfig window.
>
> Restart the computer for the changes to apply.

Set the Policy :

> Execute Gpedit.msc  from Run prompt.
>
> Goto "Computer Configuration" -> "Admin Templates" -> "Windows Components" -> "Windows   Logon Options"
>
> In Windows LogOn Option , double click "Disable enable software Secure Attention Sequence"
>   Select "Enable" option and "Services and Ease of Access application"
>
> Click OK.

[Source](http://www.manageengine.com/desktop-management-msp/rds_vista_UAC_SAS_failure_msp.html)

Comment: What if remote machine is not running windows?

Comment: Good question, I never thought about it. I think in that situation we have to find another solution. :)

Comment: `"Disable enable software Secure Attention Sequence" Select "Enable"` - had to read that 3 times to understand it!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, process manager skips that window.

In the run window for rebooting a windows server:

```
Shutdown -r
```

For shutting down:

```
Shutdown -t
```

Comment: Due to a weird situation, I had to RDC from my Mac to a Windows PC, and then from that Windows PC into another Windows PC. When the Explorer on the third PC in the chain hung up, this was the only answer that saved me.

Answer (score 3):

When logged into the remote Windows PC, right-click on the bar the bottom, which will bring up a number of options and one of them is "Show Task Manager". Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not the only thing you do with ctrl alt delete

Answer (score 3):

In windows 7 hit the start button on the machine you are connected to via RDP and then click the "Windows Security" button which effectively is the same thing as pressing Cntl-Alt-Del.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if all you can use is a command line, then you can paste

```
Powershell.exe -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -command "(new-object -ComObject shell.application).WindowsSecurity()"
```

into CMD, PowerShell, or even the little program search text box that appears when you click the Start menu Windows icon.  This simulates pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del.

I've been on servers where pretty much the only program available is the CMD shell.  Makes no sense, but it's true.

Comment: This works! I am using Citrix and this is the only suggestion that worked for me. Even the on-screen keyboard option didn't work. Thanks

Comment: This worked on a session where attempting to use OSK.exe for a ctrl-alt-del yields a "click your user tile and choose an option" message.
(Would that I were actually allowed to _paste_ into this session, though!)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, with client win8.1 and server windows server 2008 R2. 
And there was no way to open the screen to change the password remotely because no CTRL+ALT+DEL or CTRL+ALT+END worked both on client and on server.
Opening the on-screen keyboard on server also didn't worked and nothing happend.
For me, the solution was to open the on-screen keyboard on client machine, then open the remote window and press the CTRL+ALT+DEL set of keys and worked for me.