# Send CTRL-ALT-DEL to SECOND (double-hop) remote desktop in Windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, ctrl-alt-delete

I have a remote desktop that I can only access from another machine that I have to RDP (remove desktop) into. I need to send CTRL-ALT-DEL to that second machine. In otherwords, I need to 'double-hop' to a remote machine using RDP, and send CTRL-ALT-DEL to that machine.

Remote desktop client (at least in Windows, also know as Microsoft Terminal Services Client or mstsc.exe) allows you to send CTRL-ALT-DEL my pressing CTRL-ALT-END instead. In my situation, that sends CTRL-ALT-DEL to the first RDP session, and it doesn't make it to the second 'double-hopped' session.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I send a Ctrl+Alt+Delete through Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/492856/how-can-i-send-a-ctrlaltdelete-through-remote-desktop-in-windows-8)

Comment: The duplicate you referenced does have some comments that address the same answer I gave, but the question is different; that question just asks how to send CTRL-ALT-DEL to a remote desktop. It does not ask how to send it to a second / nested / double-hopped remote desktop. I did search for my question before posting but did not see anyone asking about this particular scenario. Hopefully this will help someone find the answer quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send CTRL-ALT-DEL to your second (double-hopped) RDP session, you need to be able to press CTRL-ALT-END from within your first RDP session to make it tell RDP to send CTRL-ALT-DEL to the second session.

To do that in Windows, we can use the built-in on-screen keyboard; just hit the start menu and type 'keyboard' and you should find it.

1. In your first RDP session, click the start menu and type 'keyboard' to find the on-screen keyboard.

[image: Launch on-screen keyboard]

2. Make sure your second RDP session has 'focus'. (meaning it is the active program) Just click on something in it to be sure.
3. Then in the on-screen keyboard, click CTRL, then ALT and then END.

Now you should see the typical blue Lock / Switch user / Sign out / Change password... menu appear in your second RDP session.

[image: ctrl-alt-del menu]

Comment: good tip! ugly process, but I've had this issue before and this at least works!